# What is the meaning of うち in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words

I read the definition of 本能:

> ほん-のう [1][0] 本能
> （１）生まれつきもっている性質や能力。特に，性質や能力の**うち**，非理性的で感覚的なものをいう。

I understand the 生まれつきもっている性質や能力 part as "Qualities and abilities" x holds naturally. But I don't understand the second part, especially the function of うち there. This is not the same thing as うちに so I am not sure.

Comment: "Especially, **among** (such innate) qualities and abilities, (it) refers to non-reasonable and intuitive ones."